# Trying to draw animated bitmap, not working

Tags: java, android

Ok, Im basically just trying to figure out how to draw an image that moves across the screen and then take it from there.  I've went through a couple tutorials on drawing, using paint, onDraw(), etc, and have searched the net for a while but am not sure what I've done wrong.  Basically the app loads fine and it navigates to the page but the image is never drawn.  Probly something stupid I've missed.

This is myclass "BlackJack", it is the Activity class.

```
public class BlackJack extends Activity {
BlackJackDrawCard newCard;
Deck deck;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_black_jack);
    deck = new Deck(this.getResources());
    deck.shuffle();
    newCard = new BlackJackDrawCard(this, deck.getCard(4) );
}
```

BlackJackDrawCard is this class, where I actually draw the card:

```
public class BlackJackDrawCard extends View{

    Bitmap card;
    float x, y;
    public BlackJackDrawCard(Context context, Bitmap i) {
        super(context);
        card=i;
        x=0;
        y=0;

    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        canvas.drawBitmap(card, x, y, null);
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
        invalidate();
    }


}
```

"deck" is my class that is, obviously, the deck of cards.  It contains an arrayList of 52 cards each with a value of "img", which is there respective bitmap image.  deck.getCard(i) returns the bitmap image of the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things here you might want to consider:

If the purpose of BlackJackDrawCard is to draw an image, wouldn't it be better for it to extend from ImageView?

Also, you shouldn't call invalidate inside the onDraw method - it would cause an infinite loop of drawing.

If you're going to create a view this way, you'll need to set its layout params. A way to make sure that the view will display the entire bitmap you're giving it, is to set the layout params as the width & height of the bitmap:

```
public BlackJackDrawCard(Context context, Bitmap i) 
    {
        super(context); 

        card = i;

        setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(card .getWidth(), card .getHeight())); // Assuming the view will be inside a relative layout.
    }
```

In order to Animate your view, it would be best to use the Animation classes. Here's an example:

(Inside you Activity class:)

```
public void animateCard(BlackJackDrawCard card, int amountToMoveRight, int amountToMoveDown)
{
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, amountToMoveRight, 0, amounttoMoveDown);
    animation.setDuration(1000); // duration in millisec

    card.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Hope this helps get you started :)

Comment: Wow, that actually makes a LOT of sense to me!  Thanks!